# why RH850G3K is not in Processor type list in my IDA?

Tags: ida

Why there aren't RH850 series(like RH850G3K) processors in the processor type list in my IDA? (IDA website says they are supported.)
I use IDA 7.0 pro.

Comment: I can see it in the list of the available processor types: `Renesas RH850 [RH850]`

Comment: what is your ida version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RH850 Processor type is not supported in IDA 7.0 pro.
It just has been added in IDA 7.2 pro. 
https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/7.2/index.shtml